# A question in the arithmetic of elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $K$ be a perfect field, $V$ an affine variety defined over $K$, $ K(V) $ and $\bar K(V)$ are the function field over $K$ and $\bar K(V)$ respectively. It says that $K(V)$ is the subset of $\bar K(V)$ fixed by $Gal(\bar K/K)$.But I don’t know how to prove it.

In the exercise, it proves $K[V]$ is the fixed subset of $\bar K[V]$ under $Gal (\bar K/K)$,so you can use this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How about using the fact that you can see a rational function on $V$ as a rational map into $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: One direction should be easy since elements of $K(V)$ are fractions of elements in $K[V]$.